# Call to undefined function IDENT_CURRENT()

Tags: php

SOLVED WITH  `<input type="hidden"  value="'.mysql_insert_id().'"  name="Cid" >`
solution proposed by barmar.

---

This code generate a table with item, qty and prices, im trying to allow modification of quantity.

But it says my function is undefined ??

This code generate all items one by one, it should be able to get the ID of the recently changed quantity.

```
    $sqle="SELECT * FROM soumissionmod WHERE soumissionid='$nsr' ORDER BY ARTICLE DESC ";
$resulte=mysql_query($sqle);
while($tabf = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulte))
/////////////////////////////////////////////
{

//on verifie si l article est de type travaux ou admin
if($tabf['ARTICLE']==0 AND $tabf['FORMAT']=='N/D' AND $tabf['MARQUE']=='N/D')
{
$tabf['ARTICLE']='MAIN D\'OEUVRE';
}

$compteur2++;
$id=$tabf['id'];
$prixunitaire=$tabf['PRIX']/$tabf['quantite'];

echo 
'<tr>'.

 '<td class="tdi">'.$compteur2.'</td>'.
 '<td class="td">'. $tabf['ARTICLE'].
 '</td>'.
'<td class="tdo">'. $tabf['DESCRIPTION'].'</td>'.
'<td class="td">'.$tabf['FORMAT'].'</td>'.
 '<td class="td">'.$tabf['MARQUE'].'</td>'.
 '<td class="td">'.number_format($prixunitaire,2).'</td>'.
   '<td class="tdm"> <FORM  method="post" action="xxxcontinue2.php"> <input type="text" maxlength="3" size="3" value="'.$tabf['quantite'].'"  name="newqty"> <input type="submit" value="Modifier"> 
   <input type="hidden"  value="'.IDENT_CURRENT('soumissionmod').'"  name="Cid" >    </form>   </td>'.    
 '<td class="td">'.number_format($prixunitaire,2)*$tabf['quantite'].'</td>';


 $newqty=$_POST['newqty'];
 $Cid=$_POST['Cid'];

 $mod="UPDATE `gestionj_gestionjules`.`soumissionmod` SET `quantite` = '$newqty' WHERE `soumissionmod`.`id` = $Cid";
```

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT()` is a SQL function, you're trying to call it from PHP.

Comment: Also, it's from T-SQL, not MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar Considering [their last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335166/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-select-t-string-expecting-or), do you expect them to know the difference? It's code! Let's just mash it all together and get other people to do it for me when it doesn't work!

Comment: The equivalent function in MySQL is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. You can also use the PHP function `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  Im here to find constructive comments, yes i am new to php and i didnt know sql is not related to php

Comment: @barman thank you, do i have to select your last comment as best answer or it does it automatically :/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you forget to close the while block with the curly brace:

```
while() { /* .... */ }
```

Got it when trying to run your code.

Comment: That would be a parse error, not an undefined function error.

Comment: Thank you Niet. I just think that is an overlapped error. You must be an expert in PHP.